# How to retrieve only the stores that sold more than 10 different products on any single day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Before anything else**

- The asterisked attributes in the relational database schema code below are primary keys.
- Stores with the same name but different sID (and address) form what we call a store chain.
- Purchase entity set contains every transaction (tID) which corresponds to one customer (cID) who buys from one store (sID) on one date (date);
- Two stores are considered to be different when they have a different store IDs.

The subjected relational schema:

```
customer(cID*, cName, street, city):
store(sID*, sName, street, city)
product(pID*, pName, suffix)
shoppinglist(cID*, pID*, quantity, date)
purchase(tID*, cID, sID, pID*, date, quantity, price)
inventory(sID, pID, date, quantity, unit-price)
```

I provided myself with the following **objective**: Practically to list the stores (sID and sName) that sold more than 10 different products on any single day.

The sql-code I came with looks as follows:

```
SELECT
    s.sID,
    s.sName
FROM
    store s
JOIN (
    SELECT
        i.sID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT i.pID) AS product_count
    FROM
        inventory i
    WHERE
        i.date = '2018-08-27' -- I don't know how to factor in all the dates in the data base
    GROUP BY
        i.sID
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT i.pID) > 10
) subquery ON s.sID = subquery.sID;
```

Even though I tested it and I've been given with the following results for the chosen date (2018-08-27)

```
**sID** **sName**
25  Le'Pule
26  Ulcior
36  Pizda
```

where sID represents the store's identification number and sName stands for the name of the store, *I can't figure out how to widen the searching scope from one pre-selected date ('2018-08-27') to all the dates in the database ('2018-08-27','2018-08-28, '2018-08-29' for instance).*

Therefore, is there any specific method I could use for selecting all the present dates instead of constraining the searching at one day per run?

Comment: Try WHERE i.date BETWEEN  '2018-08-27' AND  '2018-08-29'

Comment: Need to group by store and date for a daily count by store, not filter by date range. What RDBMS are you using - Access, SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle? Add appropriate tag.

Comment: If you want to count customer sales, shouldn't you use Purchase table for this?

Comment: @June7 you got a keen eye indeed.
Maybe?
Yet to be tested.
Let me verify.

Comment: @June7 I'm using a SQL Server Studio shared by Microsoft

Comment: "I'm using a SQL Server Studio shared by Microsoft".  There no such a thing as SQL Server Studio.  I assume you use SQL Server.  If it is, why do you tag `MySQL`.  They're two completely different products with different date functions!!!  Please tag your question with proper tags.

Comment: Telling us  you use management studio is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some, but alarming from an aspiring mechanic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from `purchase`, join with `store` to get the store name, and group by the store ID, name, ***and date***. Use a [`having`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause to only get those stores with more than 10 distinct sales.

```
select
  store.sID,
  store.sName,
  "date",
  count(distinct pID) as "Num Different Products"
from purchase
join store on store.sID = purchase.sID
group by store.sID, store.sName, "date"
having count(distinct pID) >= 10;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/lx183nEv).

(Some databases can figure out that because `store.sID` is the primary key `store.sName` is "functionally dependent" on it and so `group by store.sID` is sufficient to imply `store.sName`. Apparently SQL Server isn't one of them.)

---

Notes:

- Providing `create table` statements is easier for us to understand than a description.
- As you're discovering, names like `pID` are not particularly descriptive nor unique (is pID purchase or product?). I like simply using `id` for the primary key and `tableNameID` for foreign keys.
- Similarly, avoid prefixing column names with the name of the table. It's just tedious. If there's ambiguity, use the table name: `store.name`.
- Store chains should be defined using tables. One for the chain, and a join table between chains and stores. This makes the relationship explicit, allows for [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity), a place to store information about chains, and the possibility that a store in a chain might have a different name.
- `date` is a SQL keyword. If you use it as a column name, you might have to disambiguate. It's also very generic, the date of what? What if there's more than one date in the table? Instead, I suggest `event_on` for dates and `event_at` for timestamps: `purchased_on` and `purchased_at`.

Comment: Per OP "*sold more than 10 different products on any single day*". This requires grouping by purchase date as well as store. A date range filter could be applied if there is a need to restrict output to a particular period such as a year or quarter, but not filter by a single date value.